# Syntax for a SAP HANA Query with Input Parameters

Tags: sql, hana

I'm new to SAP HANA SQL syntax and am having trouble defining input parameters.  I've done several Google searches and found several different suggestions, none of which have worked.  In SQL server, I would define parameters for a query this way:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,
        @EndDate DATETIME;

SELECT EmployeeName,
       EmployeeTitle,
       Salary,
       PositionStartDate,
       PositionEndDate
FROM EmployeeData
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND PositionStartDate = @StartDate
  AND PositionEndDate = @EndDate
```

How would I write this same query in SAP HANA SQL syntax?  Any help or direction that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in above Answer code, declare endDate and used in where :enDate

Hear below sample query you can use * or column names with "," in SAP HANA DB

```
DO BEGIN

-- Declare variables
DECLARE startDate DATE;
DECLARE endDate DATE;

-- assign value startDate and endDate 
startDate := '2023-04-01';
endDate := '2023-04-12';

   SELECT 
        T0.*
   FROM "TABLENAME" T0
   WHERE 1 = 1 AND T0."FromDate" = startDate AND T0."ToDate" = endDate;

END;
```

Or

```
DO BEGIN

-- Declare variables
DECLARE startDate DATE;
DECLARE endDate DATE;

-- assign value startDate and endDate 
startDate := '2023-04-01';
endDate := '2023-04-12';

   SELECT 
        T0."column1",
        T0."column2"
   FROM "TABLENAME" T0
   WHERE 1 = 1 AND T0."FromDate" = startDate AND T0."ToDate" = endDate;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you've shown is MS SQL Servers's *T-SQL*, the procedural SQL extension, not standard SQL.

SAP HANA's equivalent is *SQLScript* and the corresponding code snippet would look like this:

```
DO BEGIN
DECLARE startDate DATE;
DECLARE endDate DATE;
   
   SELECT EmployeeName,
          EmployeeTitle,
          Salary,
          PositionStartDate,
          PositionEndDate
   FROM EmployeeData
   WHERE 1 = 1
     AND PositionStartDate = :startDate
     AND PositionEndDate = :enDate;

END;
```

Comment: Thanks, Lars Br....I'll give that a try!  I appreciate the assist!

Comment: I declared the variables as you suggested, but when I run the query get the following error message: `Syntax error or access violation; 257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "DECLARE": line 1 col 1 (at pos 1).`  I tried it this way because I received a similar message when adding `DO BEGIN` to the beginning of the query. After some additional trial and error, I was able to leave out the DECLARE statement and use an in-line declaration (as you provided above) then the query worked (and prompted me for input dates).  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: What DB client program do you use? And did you use the `:<var-name>` naming (with leading colon) as in my example? Without the `DO BEGIN` you’re not using SQLScript and then there’s only the parameters of prepared statements - which are different from your example.